# Error inserting date in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run this insert command

```
INSERT INTO DW_BATCH_HIST   
(DW_BATCH_HIST.BATCH_NBR, DW_BATCH_HIST.TRANS_START_DATE, DW_BATCH_HIST.BATCH_STATUS) 
VALUES(82,to_date('27-SEPT-2012 11:00:00.000','DD-MON-YYYY hh:mi:ss'), 1)
```

I get this error:

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

The year is a valid year, so I don't understand why I am getting this error. What am I missing?

Comment: Besides the answer from Joe Stefanelli, look at the seconds field too.

Comment: There is a *massive* clue in the fact that your date string is longer than your data mask.

Answer (score 2):

The month for the `MON` portion of the mask should be a three letter abbreviation, not four as you have it.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by others, the milliseconds should be removed as well.

```
'27-SEP-2012 11:00:00'
```

Comment: @LukasEder: Good catch. I'll remove those as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on the safe side with date / time formatting in Oracle (and most other databases), use the SQL standard timestamp literal format. In your case, write

```
TIMESTAMP '2012-09-27 11:00:00.000'
```

If that's not an option, fix your date as such:

```
to_date('27-SEP-2012 11:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY hh:mi:ss')
-- removed the T from SEPT, as well as the millisecond part
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 'SEPT' to 'SEP' and remove the milliseconds from the time value.